# ¿como deshabilitar evento javascript de un button?

Tags: php, javascript, html

tengo un button que contiene un evento de javascript, ese boton me abre un formulario el cual debe llenarse y guardase,pero solo debe hacerse una vez,como hgo para deshabilitar el button despues de guardar los datos en el formulario.

Este formulario carga la informacion de un paciente que se identifica con paci_doc,osea cada paciente contiene el evento con datos diferentes.

existe una forma de deshabilitar este boton u otra forma de decirle al usuario que el formulario para ese paciente ya esta lleno y exiete en la base de datos.

```
function VerPacientesq(cod){
var parametros = { "paci_doc": cod };

$.ajax({
data:parametros,
url:"../vista/psiquiatra/FormularioPsiquiatra.php",
 type:"POST",
 beforeSend: function(){
 $("#ventana").html("Procesando...");
 },

success: function(vista){
$("#ventana").html(vista);
}

});

}
```

Botón que contiene evento:

```
   <?php
    include'vista_psiquiatra.php'; 

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Mi Renacer</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script type="text/javascript" src ="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script><!--sirve y para prueba-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src ="js/funciones2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script><!--con este scrip se hace el filtro-->

    </head>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
     $(document).ready(function () {
     (function ($) {
     $('#filtrar').keyup(function () {
     var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
     $('.buscar tr').hide();
     $('.buscar tr').filter(function () {
     return rex.test($(this).text());
     }).show();
     })
     }(jQuery));
    });
    </script>

    <body> 
    <br>

    <div id="ventana">
    <div class="table-responsive col-sm-12">  
    <hr>
    <h5 align="center"><label>LISTA PACIENTES</label></h5>
    <hr>
    <style type="text/css">
     #filtro{
     float:right;
     }

    </style>

    <div id="filtro">
    <input id="filtrar" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar.."  >
    </div>

    <br><br><br>
    <table id="tabla" class="table table-condensed" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
     <th width="5%">C.C</th>
     <th width="5%">NOMBRE</th>
     <th width="5%">APELLIDO</th>
     <th width="5%">CELULAR</th>
     <th width="5%">EPS</th>
     <th width="5%">ESTADO CIVIL</th>
     <th width="5%">OCUPACION</th>
     <th width="5%">FECHA ING</th>
     <th width="5%">FECHA NAC</th>
     <th style='display: none;' width="5%">FAMILIAR</th>
     <th style='display: none;' width="5%">RELIGION</th>
     <th style='display: none;' width="5%">PROFESION</th>

     <th width="5%">HISTORIA <span class="fa fa-eye" style="font-size:20px"></th>   

    </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody class="buscar">
     <?php

    require_once("../modelo/ValidarDatosPsiquiatra.php");
     $listapacienteSQ=new ValidarDatosSQ();

    $listapaciente=$listapacienteSQ->ListarPacienteSQ();

    foreach($listapaciente as $registro){
    echo 
     "<tr>
    <td>".$registro['paci_doc']."</td>
    <td>".$registro['paci_nom']."</td>
    <td>".$registro['paci_ape']."</td>
    <td>".$registro['paci_cel']."</td>
    <td>".$registro['paci_eps']."</td>
    <td>".$registro['paci_esc']."</td>
    <td>".$registro['paci_ocu']."</td>
    <td>".$registro['paci_fecha_ing']."</td>
    <td>".$registro['paci_fecha_nac']."</td>
    <td style='display: none;'>".$registro['paci_aco']."</td>
    <td style='display: none;'>".$registro['paci_rel']."</td>
    <td style='display: none;'>".$registro['paci_pro']."</td>
    <td><button onclick ='VerPacientesq(".$registro['paci_doc'].");'>Crear Historia</button></td> ";//esto viene de funciones1.js

    }
        ?>
    <tbody>
    </table> 
     </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Con este codigo listo una tabla qe contiene los pacientes,cada paciente tiene el button del evento ,que se llama crear historial,desde este documento escribo un script donde se incluye el codigo.js es el segundo bajando, se llama funcines2.js,despues donde se genera la lista coloco el button con un onclick que llama a la funcion Verpacientesq, con esto permite que el onclick me muestres el formulario con losque debo llenar.este formularo esta relacionado con el aciente listado

Comment: Hola Miguel,acabe de subir el codigo completo,la funcion se incluye con un script y se relaciona en el button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo coloca un disabled button si la respuesta del servicio fue correcta.

```
function VerPacientesq(cod){
  var parametros = { "paci_doc": cod };

    $.ajax({
        data:parametros,
        url:"../vista/psiquiatra/FormularioPsiquiatra.php",
        type:"POST",
        beforeSend: function(){
        $("#ventana").html("Procesando...");
    },

        success: function(vista){
            event.target.disabled = true;
            $("#ventana").html(vista);
        }

    });
}
```

Igual, te aclaro que esto es solo a nivel visual, para que el usuario entienda que no puede volver a crear ese paciente o historial. El control lo debes hacer en el servidor y devolver la respuesta al cliente.

Espero haber entendido y haberte ayudado

Comment: Infinitas gracias Miguel.

Comment: Con gusto. Si te funcionó, por favor colócalo como mejor respuesta. Gracias!

Comment: si si, es que no se bien como funciona el sistema de calificacion, pero ya pude.